# Simple Google mapIntent not displaying

Tags: android, google-maps, mono, xamarin

I am having trouble displaying any Google Maps application. I have tried the most basic Google Maps application found here at this resource: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/platform_features/maps_and_location/part_1_-_maps_application/

The map is not being displayed...Here is a screenshot: http://www.canninginc.co.nz/ForumPost/AndroidEmulatorScreenshot.png

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace TestBuildInMapApplication
{
    [Activity (Label = "TestBuildInMapApplication", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            var geoUri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse ("geo:42.374260,-71.120824");
            var mapIntent = new Intent (Intent.ActionView, geoUri);
            StartActivity (mapIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the application output: http://www.canninginc.co.nz/ForumPost/Application_Output.txt

There is a line in the application output as follows that may be relevant:

> [Mono] AOT failed to load AOT module mscorlib.dll.so: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/TestBuildInMapApplication.TestBuildInMapApplication/lib/mscorlib.dll.so" not found

May I please have some help to display a simple Google Map? What could be wrong or what do I need to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement Google maps in android please follow the follwing links they might help you:

[link 1](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html)
or
[link 2](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

you have to follow all those steps

but please tell me in which language have you written the code? that doesn't seem to be the java code as I'm accustomed to for android, its seems like C++ code to me,

Answer (score 0):

Try testing on a real device instead of the emulator, it's way easier.  If you insist on testing on the emulator, try this [guide](http://hmkcode.com/run-google-map-v2-on-android-emulator/) to set it up properly.  There are also a number of SO threads on the issue.